# DQL drop group_name in DFC

Tags: java, dql, documentum, dfc

I have a list of group names which the app is reading from external .txt.
I want to pass to method as a `List <String>` group names and to execute dql query something like:

```
for (String s : groupnames) {
    dql = "DROP GROUP " + s;
    System.out.println("dropped group: " + s;
}
```

How to write/execute DQL?

Comment: OK, but what is your question? How to achieve it programatically? Execute DQL?

Comment: Yes, how to execute DQL to drop eache group from List <String>

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by myself:

```
private static void deleteGroups(List<String> groupsToDelete) {
    try {
        DfClientX clientX = new DfClientX();
        IDfQuery query = clientX.getQuery();

        for (String s : groupsToDelete){
            query.setDQL("DROP GROUP '" + s + "'");
            printInfo("Executing DQL: " + query.getDQL());
            query.execute(_session, 0);

        }

    } catch (DfException e) {
        printError(e.getMessage());
        DfLogger.error("app", "DQL DROP GROUP execution", null,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two points:
1) You **have** to close documentum collections. You get one when executing query.execute() method.  
If this is only a one-time activity, then it is fine. If you are using it in your application - this needs to be fixed  
2) Deleting a group may have consequences as there might be objects holding references to it.  It is better to run dm_ConsistencyChecker job and check it's output

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure does CS permit to delete group via DFC but it should be like:

```
IDfQuery query = new DfQuery();
query.setDQL("DROP GROUP <group_name>");
query.execute(getSession(), IDfQuery.DF_EXEC_QUERY);
```

There is for sure way to instantiate group object in memory and call *.delete()* method. I'll try to check it out.